# latex code didnt print images of equal size

Tags: floats, subfloats

i am working on ieee 2 column template .. i am placing 4 figures in a row but i am really wondering that the code didnt show them equal size even they sare of equal size

can any one tell me why here is my code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}% redundant
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[ aaa ]{\includegraphics{Fig5.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig5}
\subfloat [bbb]{ \includegraphics{Fig6.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccc}
    \label{Fig6}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics{Fig7.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig7}
\subfloat[bbbb]{\includegraphics{Fig8.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccccccccccccc}
\label{Fig8}
\end{minipage}
  \end{figure*}
```

Comment: I would move `\label{Fig5}` before `\hfill`.

Comment: Do all the images have the exact same aspect ratio? You've set the width to be equal, but if one is square and the other rectangular, the height will of course be different. What does the result look like?

Comment: not rectangle or square but a minor difference .. yeah all have same aspect ratio i adjusted through photoshop

Comment: I don't know what happens, they should have the same width. You're not fooled by whitespace in the images, I suppose? Do you get the same problem if you use e.g. `\includegraphics{example-image}` instead of your own images? (`example-image` is one of several images provided by a package called `mwe`. As long as that package is installed those images can be used directly.)

Comment: with example images its perfect .. you are right i thing white space is issue